# Converting a C# engine into C++ for speed

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

So this is the situation right now:
I have a C# GUI project combined with a C# Engine project in the same solution. The GUI allows interaction with the user, some high level stuff etc. The functionality of the Engine is to communicate with another third-party application. The Engine has sockets that connect to the third-party application as well has methods to convert a message into an object, send it to the third-party application, and listen for a response from the third-party application and react accordingly. Data to be communicated between the Engine and the Third-party application are packaged into objects.
The problem with the C# engine is that it's too slow. So the idea is to convert the engine to unmanaged C++ for speed.
This is my plan of attack:

1. Translate the entire C# engine by hand into C++ (which is already pretty daunting because the C# engine includes threads and hashtables)
2. Have the following to substitute for constructors, accessors, and mutators in C++:

   ```
   void* CreateInstance()
   {
       MyClass* p = new MyClass();
       return p;
   }

   void ReleaseInstance(void* pInstance)
   {
       MyClass* p = (MyClass*)pInstance;
       delete p;
   }

   int GetData(void* pInstance)
   {
       MyClass* p = (MyClass*)pInstance;
       return p->GetData();
   }

   void SetData(void* pInstance, value)
   {
       MyClass* p = (MyClass*)pInstance;
       p->SetData(value);
   }
   ```

   (The reason why I can't use real classes in C++ is because you can't instantiate C++ objects in C#)
3. Then build a C++ unmanaged DLL, use P/Invoke within the C# GUI project ([DllImport etc.]) to access all the C++ methods, and use that to replace the C# engine. Objects will be simulated using methods and passed back and forth between the C# GUI and C++ Engine.

Before I embark on this time-consuming task, is there any C# code that would be impossible to translate into C++ and then re-imported back into the C# GUI through this method?

Comment: This looks extremely error prone and not fun at all. Also, your reasoning for doing so seems misinformed.

Comment: Have you tried actually profiling your C# engine? I don't see how rewriting something that is merely waiting on sockets most of the time in a different language is going to be worth the marshaling overhead. If your C# code is using threads because it's using sockets synchronously, then you just have poor code, orthogonal to what language it's written in.

Comment: What's the performance penalty of marshaling managed values to native and back again vs. fixing your C# code? I'm not sure CLR is so much slower than native code that rewriting something in C++ would ever be a reasonable solution. Unless your managed code is marshaling managed types heavily to native types.

Comment: I would strongly advice against such conversion project at this stage of your career - if conversion of "hashtables" from C# to C++ looks like hard thing for you than it would really better to keep it as C#.

Answer (score 2):

There's not going to be any C# code that's impossible to translate into C++.  You might want to look into if there are any library functions in .NET that aren't covered by the C++ libraries you'll be working with, though. Make sure you aren't getting stuck with any wheels to reinvent.

That said, in my practical experience real-world C++ code is not naturally faster than real-world C# code.  It's true that a C++ programmer has more available tricks that can allow them to get better performance, but the effort involved in getting to that point can often be quite formidable.  Consider the famous case of the [competition between Rico Mariani and Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx).  The advantage Chen's final version enjoyed over Rico's was ultimately down to just the time the .NET run-time needed to bootstrap itself.  That's a bit of overhead that's negligible for a longer-running process.

So I would strongly encourage you to try spending some time with a performance profiler to see why the C# code is slow first, and what you can do to speed it up.  It may very well be that by going that route you can get the code running fast enough for your needs with a fraction of the effort.  It's amazing how impressive you can look just selecting better data structures.